# Do you know how to make Hebrew JSON file show correct characters in HTML page?

Tags: html, json, hebrew

I am having a problem in showing Hebrew letters on my HTML page. I am using (as far as I know maybe I'm wrong) JSON file from here:

https://getbible.net/json?scripture=Psa%20119&version=bhs

I want it to look like this one:
https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ps.119&version=WLC

But I still get only this: u05d0\u05b7\u05e9\u05c1\u05b0\u05e8\u05b5\u05d9 \u05e0\u05b9\u05e6\u05b0\u05e8\u05b5\u05d9 \u05e2\u05b5\u05d3\u05b9\u05ea\u05b8\u05d9\u05d5

I mean I want it to show all Hebrew symbols. Does anyone know how to fix that on the HTML page? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you actually _decoded_ this JSON ...?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what framework library you are using but it should be displayed correctly unless you or the library you are using escapes the unicode characters a second time (`"\u05d0"` becoming `"\\u05d0"`).

```js
var verse ={"verse_nr":1,"verse":"\u05d0\u05b7\u05e9\u05c1\u05b0\u05e8\u05b5\u05d9 \u05ea\u05b0\u05de\u05b4\u05d9\u05de\u05b5\u05d9\u05be\u05d3\u05b8\u05e8\u05b6\u05da\u05b0 \u05d4\u05b7\u05d4\u05b9\u05dc\u05b0\u05db\u05b4\u05d9\u05dd \u05d1\u05bc\u05b0\u05ea\u05b9\u05d5\u05e8\u05b7\u05ea \u05d9\u05b0\u05d4\u05d5\u05b8\u05d4\u05c3\r\n"};


document.getElementById("content").textContent = verse.verse;
```

```html
<div id="content"/>
```